# Preciso de ajuda para criar o arquivo makefile

Tags: c, makefile

```
# Baseando-se no link: https://www.embarcados.com.br/introducao-ao-makefile/

all: bancoBPE

bancoBPE: main.o
    gcc -o bancoBPE main.o -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic

# Não sei direito como compilar esse structs.h sozinho sem ter structs.c

structs.o: structs.h
    gcc -o filacirc.o filacirc.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic

filacirc.o: filacirc.c filacirc.h
    gcc -o filacirc.o filacirc.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic

pilhaseq.o: pilhaseq.c pilhaseq.h
    gcc -o pilhaseq.o pilhaseq.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic

lista.o: lista.c lista.h
    gcc -o lista.o lista.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ bancoBPE
```

Ocorreu o seguinte erro no terminal:

```
$ make
gcc -o bancoBPE main.o -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be         used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:5: recipe for target 'bancoBPE' failed
make: *** [bancoBPE] Error 1
```

Se alguém puder passar um material para que eu possa estudar melhor, agradeceria. Estou tentando entender direito como o makefile funciona, mas ainda sem muito sucesso apesar de ler algumas referências.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makefiles têm estrutura muito simples:

```
alvo: ingredientes
    regra
```

Onde `alvo` é o nome do arquivo que vai ser criado pela `regra` e depende dos `ingrediantes` (arquivos).

Um Makefile sempre tem uma receita principal (a primeira regra), como em:

```
bancoBPE: main.o structs.o pilhaseq.o lista.o filecirc.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Aqui, $@ é substituído pelo `alvo` e $^ por todos os `ingredientes`. A variável CC é o compilador C (aqui usado como linker).

Com base nos ingrediantes o *make* decide quais outras receitas devem ser availadas... Se *main.o* não existe, ele availará a receita para contruí-lo, por exemplo... Ou, se *main.c*, na receita onde o `alvo` é *main.o* tiver um *timestamp* mais novo que o arquivo *main.o* (o alvo), então a regra é executada:

```
main.o: main.c structs.h lista.h pilhaseq.h filecirc.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Aqui, $< é o primeiro item da lista de `ingredientes` e a variável CFLAGS é usada para informar oas opções para o compilador.

Felizmente *make* fornece alguns atalhos... Ele sabe como compilar arquivos .c e a *regra* pode ser omitida. Acima, precisaríamos apenas de:

```
main.o: main.c structs.h lista.h pilhaseq.h filecirc.h
```

O *make* ainda permite alvos "fake", como, por exemplo:

```
all: bancoBPE

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ bancoBPE
```

Mas é prudente que, se estamos usando o *GNU make*, usemos também a pseudo-receita:

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

Para dizer para o *make* que nem *all* e nem *clean* são arquivos. Assim, vocẽ pode chamar o *make* com:

```
$ make all  # all é assumido, se não informado
$ make clean
```

Acho o uso de *all* útil apenas nos casos onde existem dois ou mais alvos "principais".

O *make* também define, por si só, as variáveis CC e CFLAGS, respectivamente, "cc" e "" (string vazia), mas você pode mudá-las no início do arquivo Makefile:

```
CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
CFLAGS=-O2 -march=native -msse4.2
```